# What does setting NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground "do under the hood"?

Tags: ios, c, sockets, ios5

I have an in-house app (not for iPhone store distribution, so not subject to Apple approval) which needs to keep a handful of TCP and UDP sockets bound while it is running.

While testing I have noticed some odd behavior with my bound socket - it gets closed whenever the device goes to sleep. This happens, for example, when you depress the power button on top of the phone, and I **really** don't want it to do that. Not to mention that it seems like a gross violation of the BSD sockets API contract.

The socket code is all written in C, so isn't using the Objective-C [nsstream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) libraries.

I noticed that there are various ways to keep sockets open for things like VOIP, music streaming, and other things. The nsstream documentation itself lists a `NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground` property which seems like it might help my app keep its socket open when the phone goes to sleep. The bottom of the apple docs list the following properties:

> **Constants**
>
> `NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP`
>   
> Specifies that the stream is providing VoIP service.
>
> `NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVideo`
>   
> Specifies that the stream
>   is providing video service.
>
> `NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground`
>   
> Specifies that the
>   stream is providing a background service.
>
> `NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoice`
>   
> Specifies that the stream is providing voice service.

But since my app's network code isn't using the Objective-C API's, I need to know: how are the above constants implemented? Maybe there is an undocumented socket option that I can use to achieve the same result? Basically I just need to tell the kernel not to mess with my socket when the device sleeps.

**edit**: as an alternative to reverse engineering kernel calls, maybe there is a way to pass my socket file descriptors to Objective-C code where these options can be applied?

Comment: Though do note that NAT devices may reap "inactive" TCP sessions at any time and the remote peer may send TCP keepalive pings in addition to in-protocol keepalive pings.

Comment: @sarnold thanks, i understand that. this is a bound socket and i don't expect incoming communications to cross nat boundaries.

Comment: I vaguely recall you could toll-free-bridge between C sockets and NSStream objects. I'd have to look that up though.

Comment: Oops, I just saw this thread was more than a year old. At least my answer could help the community

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CFStream for networking you can do this:

```
NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
```

After that you can use the constants you already found with the ObjC `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream`. (`NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` both extend `NSStream`.)

Answer (score 0):

clientSocket c socket and must have already been connected, then use object c:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSInputStream *inputStream ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOutputStream *outputStream ;

CFReadStreamRef readStreamRef = nil ;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStreamRef = nil ;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(NULL, clientSocket, &readStreamRef, &writeStreamRef) ; // the socket must have already been connected.
_inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStreamRef ;
_outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStreamRef ;
[_inputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType] ;
[_outputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType] ;
[_inputStream open] ;
[_outputStream open]
```