# How to use NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, background

I found the key `NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground` in file NSStream.h file. It is declared as

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground     NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0);
```

This means, it is available in iOS 5 onwards.
However, in plist I could not find one matching backgrounding mode to be set for this.
Does anybody have any idea on how to use this?

The app would be posted to app store, so want a approved way of doing it.

BR,
Akshay Shah.

Comment: Did you ever find out more about this key?

Comment: Nope.. did not find anything on it yet..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CFStream for networking you can do this:

```
NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
```

After that you can use the constants (not sure about appstore though)

[What does setting NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground "do under the hood"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220329/what-does-setting-nsstreamnetworkservicetypebackground-do-under-the-hood)

Comment: David, perhaps I'm missing something but this appears to be irrelevant and doesn't answer the question about what NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeBackground is.  Care to explain?